# Trying to figure out a Copy Constructor for the course class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

This is the course class in question.

```
class Course {
    //** You may not change the declarations in this private: area.
    CourseName name;           ///< Name of the course
    int numberOfPrerequisites; ///< How many prereqs are currently in the array?
    int maxPrerequisites;      ///< How many prereqs will fit into the array?
    CourseName * prereqs;
```

Here is what I have as of now. Note that this copy constructor causes some of my unit tests to fail. I cannot change the unit test but instead must fix the copy constructor:

```
Course::Course(const Course& other)
    : name(other.name), numberOfPrerequisites(other.numberOfPrerequisites),
      maxPrerequisites(other.maxPrerequisites), prereqs(new CourseName[other.maxPrerequisites])
{
    // Copy all prerequisites
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPrerequisites; ++i)
    {
        prereqs[i] = other.prereqs[i];
    }
}
```

The unit test that are failing say that once a new course is initialized using another course, when you modify the newly create course it is also changing the original course. Simply put they are the same after modifications when they should be different.

These are the operator overloads that I have tried thus far.

```
bool Course::operator==(const Course& other) const
{
    return name == other.name;
}
```

```
Course& Course::operator=(const Course& other)
{
    if (this == &other)
        return *this;

    name = other.name;
    numberOfPrerequisites = other.numberOfPrerequisites;
    maxPrerequisites = other.maxPrerequisites;

    delete[] prereqs;

    prereqs = new CourseName[other.maxPrerequisites];

    // Copy the prerequisites from the source object to the new object
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPrerequisites; ++i)
    {
        prereqs[i] = other.prereqs[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Recommendations: Make sure `CourseName` is correctly observing [the Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and replace `CourseName * prereqs;` with `std::vector<CourseName> prereqs;` and `Course` can observe the Rule of Zero. Then you get the pleasure of doing absolutely nothing! In general the lower down in the stack you can place any specialized copying logic, the better because everything above is dumb-old Rule of Zero.

Comment: Ahh. I read a bit deeper. You are explicitly required to write code like a moron. I feel for you.

Comment: But you may be allowed to implement the assignment operator via [Copy and Swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/4581301). That's always a good starting position. It may not be optimal performance, but it's next to impossible to get wrong and testing will let you know if it's too slow.

Comment: Assuming `CourseName` is Rule of 3/5/0 compliant, I don't see anything wrong with that copy constructor. I think we need to see a [mre] (assuming making the example doesn't end early with you finding and fixing the mistake and the question becomes useless (consider self answering in that case to try to salvage the question)).

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is that the equality `operator==` should compare the same members that are copied in the copy ctor. That way, if you make a copy, the copy will be equal to the original. There are, however, exceptions to the rule. To be equal, for example, two instances of class `Course` should have the same name and the same list of prerequisites. They may not, however, need to have the same `maxPrerequisites`. These considerations suggest that the equality `operator==` given in the question is deficient.

Comment: Did your instructor say anything about needing a destructor function (a.k.a. dtor)? Class `Course` seems to be following the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), but it is missing a dtor.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a homework assignment of some sort, so I do not want to give away too much in this answer.

That said, the comments have identified these things:

1. The copy-ctor appears to be okay.
2. So does the copy-assignment `operator=`.
3. The dtor is missing.
4. The equality `operator==` is deficient.

The missing dtor will cause memory leaks. Its absence, however, should not cause the copy-ctor or copy-assignment `operator=` to fail.

> The unit test that are failing say that once a new course is initialized using another course, when you modify the newly create course it is also changing the original course.

If the copy-ctor is doing its job correctly–which seems to be the case–then the only thing that could be going wrong is the copying of `CourseName`.

At first, I assumed it had a straightforward definition such as this:

```cpp
struct CourseName
{
    std::string name;
    bool operator== (CourseName const&) const = default;
};
```

But if that were true, then there would be no error in the copy-ctor.

That is when it occurred to me that this is a lesson about deep-copy and deep-compare. Did the instructor implement `CourseName` so that it, too, would require the "Rule of Three?"

```cpp
struct CourseName
{
    char const* name_{ nullptr };
public:
    CourseName(char const* name);

    // Rule of Three
    ~CourseName();
    CourseName(CourseName const& other);
    CourseName& operator=(CourseName const& other);

    // Other member functions and operators
    bool operator== (CourseName const& other) const;
};
```

If so, then the compiler-supplied, default copy-assignment `operator=` for `CourseName` would not do the right thing. Neither would an equality `operator==` that did member-wise comparison.

Your problem, therefore, may be that you need to work on `CourseName` a bit more.

If, not, then we will need to see a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to analyze further. That should be a complete program, including function `main`. An MRE excludes unnecessary detail, but otherwise reproduces the error.

###### What is the "Strong Guarantee?"

The so-called "strong guarantee" is a promise that when an operator such as `operator=` or `operator>>` fails, the original object is left untouched. It's all-or-nothing: no partial updates are allowed.

The `operator=` given in the original question does not provide the strong guarantee. It is possible that the call to operator `new[]` could fail, throwing `std::bad_alloc`. When that happens, you will not be able to recover the original object, because you will have already deleted it.

In order to provide the strong guarantee, you need to assign the result of operator `new[]` to to a temporary variable, and only update the object *after* that pointer has been safely received.

This is your `operator=`, with only the few changes needed to provide the strong guarantee.

```cpp
Course& Course::operator=(const Course& other)
{
    if (this == &other)
        return *this;

    // If the call to operator new[] is going to fail, 
    // we need that to happen before we start deleting 
    // the original object. That is why we do this first.
    auto temp = new CourseName[other.maxPrerequisites];

    // Operator new[] did not throw std::bad_alloc.
    // Now it is safe to start overwriting things.
    name = other.name;
    numberOfPrerequisites = other.numberOfPrerequisites;
    maxPrerequisites = other.maxPrerequisites;

    delete[] prereqs;

    // Assign the temporary pointer created above.
    prereqs = temp;

    // Copy the prerequisites from the source object to the new object
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPrerequisites; ++i)
    {
        prereqs[i] = other.prereqs[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

As identified in the comments, the *copy-and-swap* idiom is an alternative way to implement `operator=`. Copy-and-swap has the benefit of simplicity, and, in addition, provides the strong guarantee.

Comment: I implemented a destructor I just failed to show it in the original question, my apologies. The courseName class does already have the Rule of Three satisfied and that code needs to remain untouched. My issue with the operator== is that I can't figure out how to write it so that it checks for the same courseName as well as the same prereq array.

Comment: First compare `this->numberOfPrerequisites` against `other.numberOfPrerequisites`. If they are the same, run a loop `for (std::size_t i{}; < numberOfPrerequisites; ++i) ...`. Inside the loop use an if-statement to compare corresponding elements. To be extra cautious, you could even sort the arrays on `CourseName`, before running a loop to compare them.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I don't see how fixing `operator==` would fix the error you describe in the original question: "when you modify the newly create course it is also changing the original course." That is the kind of symptom you see when a shallow-copy is used instead of a deep-copy.

Comment: I just took another look at your copy-ctor and copy-assignment operator. Once again, I began to suspect that `CourseName` is the culprit. Can you edit the original question, and post the complete source code for `CourseName`, along with its member functions?